# How am I to find the minimum value?

Tags: python

I wrote a short program with the intent to return the smallest number inputted by the user, why is my code not working?

```
def find_min(a,b):
    """This program finds the smaller value, a or b."""
    if (a > b):
        b = smallest
    elif (a < b):
        a = smallest
    return smallest
print("Enter value for 'a'")
value_one = float(input(">>> "))
print("Enter value for 'b'")
value_two = float(input(">>> "))
find_min(value_one, value_two)
```

Comment: You are assigning `smallest` to `a` or `b`, you should reverse that. `smallest = a`

Comment: Also what if they're equal?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you cannot use [min](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min)?

Answer (score 1):

You did not declare smallest which you used in the code. But if you do declare smallest, it should have been smallest = a, smallest = b. Not the other way around.

Here is a working version:

```
def find_min(a,b):
    """This program finds the smaller value, a or b."""
    if (a > b):
        return b
    else (a < b):
        return a
print("Enter value for 'a'")
value_one = float(input(">>> "))
print("Enter value for 'b'")
value_two = float(input(">>> "))
print("The smallest value is: " + str(find_min(value_one, value_two)))
```

Also, you can simply consider using `min(a,b)`

Comment: ``"You did not declare smallest which you used in the code."`` - you did not declare it either.

Comment: `"NameError: name 'smallest' is not defined"` if a == b

Answer (score 1):

You can use `min` to get minimum of two numbers. Try this way:

```
print("Enter value for 'a'")
value_one = float(input(">>> "))
print("Enter value for 'b'")
value_two = float(input(">>> "))
#find_min(value_one, value_two)
print(min(value_one,vakue_two))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `min`

```py
print("Enter value for 'a'")
value_one = float(input(">>> "))
print("Enter value for 'b'")
value_two = float(input(">>> "))
print(min(value_one, value_two))
```

---

If you don't want to use `min`, `find_min`  function should be like this:

```py
def find_min(a,b):
    """This program finds the smaller value, a or b."""
    if a > b:
        return b
    else:
        return a

print("Enter value for 'a'")
value_one = float(input(">>> "))
print("Enter value for 'b'")
value_two = float(input(">>> "))
print(find_min(value_one, value_two))
```

---

ps. Unlike C or Java, Python doesn't use `()` in `if`.
ps2. You don't need to use `float` for input. If you want float output, use `float` at calculated output

```py
print("Enter value for 'a'")
value_one = input(">>> ")
print("Enter value for 'b'")
value_two = input(">>> ")
print(float(find_min(value_one, value_two)))
```

Comment: If you don't use float, it takes the values as string and does string comparision. So, the `min('11','2')` will be `'11'`. You need to typecast the variables to float

Comment: Yes, You're right. My fault

Answer (score 0):

smallest is not declared in your code
plus you can use **min()** builtin function in python

---

read more >> [builtins in python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_functions.asp) or [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)

```
value_one = float(input("Enter value for 'a'\n>>>")) 
value_two = float(input("Enter value for 'b'\n>>>"))

print("The smallest value is: " + str(min(value_one, value_two)))
```